# How can I download and archive my entire EE website?

Tags: backup

My client is moving to a different platform and they want me to "download" their current EE site so they can have an archive of it.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the server the site is hosted, and either use ftp or ssh to copy the entire directory to a local machine. You will also need to export the database, which should be specified in `system > expressionengine > config > database.php`. You can do this in phpmyadmin by finding the appropriate database, select the export tab, and save as a sql file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an viewable archive of the whole site? If so [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) is what I use in such a case. Let's you grab the whole site and if you want you put it on an CD-Rom, DVD or USB-Stick to view and browse offline.

Answer (score 0):

to make it user-readable, back in the day, I used to use a feature in Acrobat that allowed you to convert a site to a multi-page pdf. Links worked and everything. No Idea if its in the current version...

Why do they want move away from EE?